# How to use lemas list on python

Tags: python, preprocessor

a has a problem:
I'm using python to analysis data.First I using lemmas list (lemas.txt) to preprocess my data.
I have lemmas list :
Eg:

```
A-bomb -> A-bombs
abacus -> abacuses
abandon -> abandons,abandoning,abandoned
abase -> abases,abasing,abased
abate -> abates,abating,abated
abbess -> abbesses
abbey -> abbeys
abbot -> abbots
```

.....
Can you help me to using my list to clear my data by python.Thanks

Comment: could you be more specify it is very unclear of what you are asking

Comment: I had  lemmas list in lemas.txt, and i need to add it to my python code to clear my data..But I didn't have any idea to do it.

Comment: so you want to create a list from the text file that is the second word's should be created as a list

Comment: @HoàngNhật, I assume you want to clean your data by converting all words that appear on the right to the match on the left, correct? Is your data already in the program?

Comment: Sorry for my bad at English, and my question was unclearly. I had a file that had list of lemas above, very large, with 40,569 words (tokens) in 14,762 lemma groups. I intend to repair a sentence in my data by using lemas, example: "I went to school" will change " I go to school" . My list lemmas also has go -> goes,went, gone,going.

Comment: @Cyphase, yes , ^^ , My data already in  my program..But i didn't know how to apply it into my data (python )

Comment: Put the data of the file in a dictionary (keys taken from the right side), split your sentence in words, replace words that you find in the dictionary.

Comment: @HoàngNhật, what format is your data in? One large string? A list of words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will parse your lemmas file and put them into a dict, where the keys are words that will be replaced and the value is what they'll be replaced with.

```
def parse_lemmas(leema_lines):
    for line in lemmas_lines:
        target, from_words_str = line.split(' -> ')
        from_words = from_words_str.split(',')
        for word in from_words:
            yield (word, target)


with open('lemmas.txt', 'r') as lemmas_file:
    lemmas = dict(parse_lemmas(lemma_line.strip() for lemma_line in lemmas_file))

# The dictionary lemmas now has all the lemmas in the lemmas file
```

Once you have your data separated into a list of words, you can run the following code.

```
# if your data isn't too large
new_data = [lemmas.get(word, word) for word in data]

# if it's so large you don't want to make another copy,
# you can do it in-place
for idx, word in data:
    data[idx] = lemmas.get(word, word)
```

Note that the data doesn't have to be just words; for example, you could split `"This is your data. This, here, is your data with punctuation; see?"` into `['This', 'is', 'your', 'data', '.', 'This', ',', 'here', ',', 'is', 'your', 'data', 'with', 'punctuation', ';', 'see', '?']`. The punctuation would just be passed through in this case. The best way to do this depends on your actual data and what information you need to retain when splitting/recombining.

Comment: thank  , My data is large string, a lot of sentences.

Comment: Do you have code that will split that string into words?

Comment: No, but I can do it, a don't how to using the code above in my code ?

Comment: @HoàngNhật, I've updated the answer; let me know if you need any more help :).

Comment: @HoàngNhật, I see you've accepted the answer; glad I could help :).

Comment: I had a error  :
lemmas.get(word, word)
'generator' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Woops! This line should be `lemmas = dict(parse_lemmas(lemma_line.strip() for lemma_line in lemmas_file))`. I fixed it in my code.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It work and I continue my process. Thank you again. :) @Cyphase